# Elements disappearing from array

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a smart contract with the field `bytes32[] public listSlas;` which contains a list of sha3 hashes.

On top of the smart contract, I have a webapp which needs to retrieve the content of that list (through the library web3js). The content is retrieved thourgh the following getter function.

```
function getSlas()
    public
    view
    returns(bytes32[])
{
    return listSlas;
}
```

The function where I add elements to the array is the following:

```
function createSLA(bytes32 _from, bytes32 _to)
    public
{
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(_from, _to);        
    listSlas.push(hash);
}
```

My problem is that the array randomly 'deletes' some of the previously inserted elements when I push one new element to it. What is the reason?

Comment: Are you testing it on mainnet or on a testnet? Can you share the address of your contract so we can see what happened?

Comment: It's on a private node

Comment: What is the type of the `listSlas` variable?

Comment: As written in the question it is a list of `bytes32`

Comment: When you say that entries are randomly deleted what do you mean? old entries are replaced by zero, or are replaced by new ones. Once you pushed data to an storage array you cannot delete it unless you have done it explicitly. The function you show in the question only append new entries and list existing entries so they should not delete previous entries, perhaps you are calling some other function that unintentionally delete them.

Comment: I don't have a function to delete the entries. When I deploy the contract, the list is already filled in with 2 elements equal to 0 despite no pushes happened. They literally disappear and it happened that after entering a couple of other hashes, the old entries would reappear